# android findViewById returns null in onoptionsitemselected

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I've got a LinearLayout in my layout folder, called "settings_caching_popup.xml" I tried to geth this layout in the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method for showing a popup. But `findViewById(R.layout.settings_caching_popup)` returns always null. Then I set an ID in the xml Layout to the LinearLayout with `android:id="@+id/settings_caching_popup` and called `findViewById(R.id.settings_caching_popup)`. Returns also null.

Pullout of the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`:

```
PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(context);

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.settings_caching_popup);

popUp.setContentView(ll);
popUp.showAtLocation(ll, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
popUp.update(50, 50, 300, 80);
```

Comment: the method `findViewById` is looking for an element that is inside the view of the activity,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inflate the layout you want to show in the popup. `findViewById()` only returns views, that already have been inflated.

Try this:

```
final PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(context);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final LinearLayout ll =
    (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_caching_popup, null);
popUp.setContentView(ll);
ll.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        popUp.showAtLocation(ll, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
        popUp.update(50, 50, 300, 80);
    }
});
```

Notice, that `this` in `LayoutInflater.from(this);` has to be your activity. So, if you want to call this from an `OnClickListener` or something similar, you need to put `YourActivity.this` there.

Comment: could you explain me, what the `ll.post` exactly do? Opens another thread? Is this necessary or "just" a smarter way? (Didn't do this before, maybe I should do it from time to time?)

Comment: I don't know exactly why this is necessary, but if you don't use `post()`, showing the popup will fail with a token is null exception. That is because `ll.getWindowToken()` returns null at this point. It seems, like the creation of the view is partly done asynchronous. Code that is posted using the `post()` method is run after the creation is complete, so that `getWindowToken()` no more returns null. Maybe someone else is able to explain this better...

Comment: Oh and `post()` does not start another thread. The runnable that is passed will be executed on the GUI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `findViewById` until the view that you're looking for has been inflated from the underlying xml.  My guess is that the view you're looking for needs to be inflated first.  The main inflation of views typically occurs on `onCreate(...)` with lines like `setContentView(...)`.  For the menus, inflation also occurs in `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)` where you see things like:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);

    // findViewById will now work for views related to the options menu
}
```

For views which are not menus, use the `LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE` as follows

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_caching_popup, null);
View childView = findViewById(R.id.childView); // view in R.layout.settings_caching_popup
```

As noted elsewhere here, use `R.id.` in `findViewById` and `R.layout.` with the inflater service.

Comment: I inflated always another view in the onCreateOptionsMenu: the menu itself. And if I click on one of this items, I want to show a popup which is in another xml without menu structure.

Comment: yeah, it does! And thank you for the note! Hm, couldn't accept two answers?!

Comment: But if you want, you can mark as many answers as you want as useful ... ?

Answer (score 1):

you are using:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.settings_caching_popup);
```

the method is Find View by **ID**, so you should get it by it's ID

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settings_caching_popup);
```

Comment: I tested both, didn't work. Thanks of the other answers I could say why: I didn't inflate the view...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[parent view of settings_caching_popup].findViewById(R.id.settings_caching_popup);
```

instead of

```
findViewById(R.id.settings_caching_popup);
```

`findViewById()` is looking for views within the layout that was inflated for the activity when you called `setContentView()` (or something similar)

Comment: Theres no parent view, `settings_caching_popup` is the root layout of this view

Comment: sounds like your solution is inflating that layout then, as other answers have suggested.